# '95 Chevy Blazer suddenly refuses to start

Tags: chevrolet, starting, ignition, blazer, s10

While driving my '95 Chevy Blazer (4.3L V6) on the highway, I pulled off to use a rest stop. The engine was (and has) been running/starting well, and upon returning to leave, the engine would not start. The engine was turning over, but would not ignite. Here's what I know:

- Battery is good, (even tried getting a jump just in case)
- The fuel pump is active, (I can hear the pump when turning key to on position, and verified there was some pressure using fuel rail schrader valve - I didn't have a pressure gauge to deteremine *how much* pressure there was, but it was pressurized)
- All 6 spark plugs, engine oil, tranny fuild, air & oil filter were replaced last month.
- Ignition Coil is sending spark

Any ideas what could be up with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it sound like it *wants* to start but won't? Or does it just spin over and over without ever sounding like it has any life whatsoever?

Comment: Also, have you checked to the fuses for the injectors? There are probably three total. If you aren't getting anything on either, it's probably the main one.

Comment: Thanks for your help & input @Paulster2! I was able to resolve the issue, it ended up being the fuel pressure regulator, so I'm going to write an answer with more information now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I got it running! Just want to post an answer for anybody else that runs across this issue.

It ended up being the **Fuel Pressure Regulator** on the CPI Injector Spider.

This is a small and cheap ($35.00) part that is mounted on the side injector. and was very straightforward to replace. I simply had to remove the upper intake manifold, and all the necessary sensors/hoses/cables to access the injector spider, and replace the regulator.

To determine that the issue was in fact the fuel pressure regulator, and not the fuel pump, I first checked the fuel pressure and saw that it was very low. I then blocked the fuel return line to the gas tank, and checked the pressure again. Pressure was very high.

So basically, my regulator failed, and was sending all of the fuel directly back to the gas tank.

Swapped out the regulator, and she fired right up!

Hope this helps! Feel free to comment or message me if anybody has any questions!